How can I find out in PLSQL from where the data is inserted into the table?
I'm using this code to search all packages, triggers, functions etc... where the table is located
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(100) := 'DATREDPUB';
BEGIN
  FOR dep IN (SELECT NAME, TYPE, REFERENCED_TYPE
              FROM USER_DEPENDENCIES
              WHERE REFERENCED_NAME = v_table_name
              AND REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE')
  LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( dep.NAME);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

As a result I get a list of all packages, triggers, functions etc... where there is also a select from the table or just an entry in the comment. Then searching e.g. 200packages for one table is tedious.
Is there any way to find out just such packages, triggers, functions etc.. that only perform insert or marge into the table?
I've tried this, but without success.
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(100) := 'DATREDPUB';
BEGIN
  FOR dep IN (SELECT NAME, TYPE, REFERENCED_TYPE
              FROM USER_DEPENDENCIES
              WHERE REFERENCED_NAME = v_table_name
              AND REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE')
  LOOP
    IF dep.TYPE = 'PACKAGE' THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Objekt: ' || dep.NAME || ', Typ: ' || dep.REFERENCED_TYPE || ', Op: PROCEDURE');
    ELSIF dep.TYPE = 'TRIGGER' THEN
      IF dep.NAME LIKE 'BI_%' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Objekt: ' || dep.NAME || ', Typ: ' || dep.REFERENCED_TYPE || ', Op: INSERT');
      ELSIF dep.NAME LIKE 'BU_%' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Objekt: ' || dep.NAME || ', Typ: ' || dep.REFERENCED_TYPE || ', Op: UPDATE');
      ELSIF dep.NAME LIKE 'BD_%' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Objekt: ' || dep.NAME || ', Typ: ' || dep.REFERENCED_TYPE || ', Op: DELETE');
      ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Objekt: ' || dep.NAME || ', Typ: ' || dep.REFERENCED_TYPE || ', Op: UNKNOWN');
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/


Another approach is to first use all_dependencies to find all related code units and then compile them using PL/Scope to capture the usage details. (You should probably do this in a test environment, not production.)
begin
    execute immediate q'[alter session set plscope_settings = 'STATEMENTS:ALL']';

    for r in (
        select distinct 'alter '||replace(d.type, ' BODY')||' '||d.name||' compile' as sql_text
        from   user_dependencies d
        where  d.referenced_name = 'DATREDPUB'
        and    d.referenced_type = 'TABLE'
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.sql_text);
        execute immediate r.sql_text;
    end loop;

    execute immediate q'[alter session set plscope_settings = 'STATEMENTS:NONE']';
end;
/

The code first alters the session so that all compilations get plscope_settings = 'STATEMENTS:ALL' applied, then compiles every code unit that has a dependency on your table. To do this for one named package, it's
alter package xyz compile body plscope_settings = 'STATEMENTS:ALL';

Now you can find SQL statements. Notice that it gives you SQL IDs, which link to all the v$sql* views, SQL Monitor, ASH, AWR etc:
select s.owner
     , s.object_name
     , s.object_type
     , (select regexp_substr(so.text, '[^ ]+', 1, 2)
        from   all_source so
        where  so.owner = s.owner
        and    so.name = s.object_name
        and    so.type = s.object_type
        and    so.line < s.line
        and    regexp_like(so.text,'^\s*(PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)\s+', 'i')
        order by so.line fetch first row only ) as subprogram
     , s.line
     , s.col
     , s.sql_id
     , s.text
from   all_statements s
where  s.type = 'INSERT'
and    s.text like '%INTO DATREDPUB %'
order by s.line, s.col;

which for my test case, gave me



OWNER
OBJECT_NAME
OBJECT_TYPE
LINE
SUBPROGRAM
COL
SQL_ID
TEXT




HR
HR_DEMO
PACKAGE BODY
10
add_department
9
3u8m21sjaux7j
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS ( DEPARTMENT_ID , DEPARTMENT_NAME , MANAGER_ID , LOCATION_ID ) VALUES ( DEPARTMENTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL , :B3 , :B2 , :B1 ) RETURNING DEPARTMENT_ID INTO :O0



(More details here.)

While this won't help with dynamic SQL or anonymous blocks, this is a pretty nifty trick to know about for complex PL/SQL systems. Great contribution!

What you are attempting to do is not easy. First, user_dependencies only has hard (compilation) dependencies in it. If you use any dynamic SQL (execute immediate) you won't find the table usage by examining dependencies.
So, you might instead use user_source and string match out the table name. But your code may be using a synonym or a view or other form of abstraction (like dynamic SQL that works with objects defined programmatically/by variable), and not actually find the table name string in the source.
Thirdly, neither user_source nor user_dependencies are going to tell you anything about anonymous PL/SQL blocks - or just plain SQL - submitted by clients but not stored in the database.
And, as you've discovered, none of the above can (easily) tell you how the table is being used. You wouldn't want to get into the business of string parsing source code and trying to identify the complete SQL in which a table reference is embedded.
If it truly is necessary to determine the kind of statement that uses a table and you are only thinking of its use in SQL (you mention inserts and merges) you can use SQL plan data in the shared pool. You'll need the select any dictionary priv to do this.
For cursors still in the pool:
SELECT sp.*,s.program_id,s.program_line#,NVL(p.object_name,o.object_name) object_name, p.procedure_name,s.sql_text
  FROM (SELECT inst_id,sql_id,operation,object_name
          FROM gv$sql_plan
         WHERE object_name = 'MYTABLENAME'
           AND operation IN ('LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL','LOAD AS SELECT','MERGE')) sp,
       gv$sqlarea s,
       user_procedures p,
       user_objects o
 WHERE sp.sql_id = s.sql_id       
   AND sp.inst_id = s.inst_id
   AND s.program_id = p.object_id(+)
   AND s.program_id = o.object_id(+)

For older cursors that have aged out of the pool it's more difficult because while you have dba_hist_sql_plan, there's no historical program_id stored in dba_hist_sqlstat to tie it to the program of origin. You'd have to use dba_hist_active_sess_history and utilize the plsql_object_id and plsql_subprogram_id fields, assuming that its activity has been recently captured and preserved after Oracle drops 9 out of 10 of its one-second samples when storing ASH data to disk.
In reality, all the above methods can and should be leveraged in tandem to be as exhaustive as you can to find out what is inserting data into a table.

Try it like below:
SELECT      ud.NAME, ud.TYPE, ud.REFERENCED_TYPE, 
            src.LINE, src.TEXT
FROM        USER_DEPENDENCIES ud
INNER JOIN  dba_source src ON(src.NAME = ud.NAME)
WHERE       ud.REFERENCED_NAME = 'LOG_TABLE' And
            ud.REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE' And 
            Upper(src.TEXT) Like Upper('%INSERT%LOG_TABLE%') Escape '\'

/*     R e s u l t :
NAME    TYPE          REFERENCED_TYPE LINE  TEXT
------  ------------  --------------- ----  ---------------------------------------
LOGGER  PACKAGE BODY  TABLE             61  "           INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE "      */

... use all_source if you don't have access to dba_source. all_source will include stored objects accessible to current user
